# How to say: "X differs from Y by(in) Z"

Tags: grammar-choice, syntax, grammar-identification

I want to say something of this sort:

> The word *"res"* differs from the word *"rex"* by one letter.

In "Lexicon totius Latinitatis" I saw under the [term "dama"](https://books.google.com/books?id=tTPCo6Nger4C&pg=PA567&dq=%22Differt%20a%20capreis%20solis%20cornibus%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEl__TwPvmAhVFPFAKHc61DE4Q6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22Differt%20a%20capreis%20solis%20cornibus%22&f=false):

> "[Dama] differt a capreis solis cornibus, quæ in anteriorem pártem habet incurvata"

My understating is that this formulation from the above quote indeed answers my question. Namely:

> **X** differt a **Y**(albative) **Z**(ablative)

([Dama] differs from caprea only by the antlers)

But I'm not sure that my understating is correct. I have hard time trying to validate this by other examples. Also I wonder of other alternatives to formulate such an expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct.
This is *ablativus respectus*, the ablative of respect.
If you look up this kind of ablative in your favourite Latin grammar, you will find examples, although not necessarily about differences.
If X and Y differ **with respect to Z**, that is expressed simply by putting Z in ablative.

The word order is flexible, and in some cases it might help to phrase things so that the ablatives of X and Z are not right next to each other.
This can be helped by putting *differt* between the two ablatives.

An alternative worth considering is making both X and Y subjects:
*X[nom] et Y[nom] Z[abl] differunt*.